# Can I use the zbar sdk in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, zbar-sdk

I have integrated the zbarsdk in my iPhone app . Working well . Now Please tell me Can I use the zbarsdk without any payments or need to pay ? and Will Apple approve it ? . I have searched but no use

Comment: Check http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/licensing.html

Comment: Ya you can use Zbarsdk without any license.I have used that and Apple had approve it..

Comment: @ACB thank you so much and +1 for you

Comment: @ShwetaThakar Thank you so much +1 for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check their [licensing page here](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/licensing.html). You dont need to pay anything to use it. Just follow whatever is mentioned there.